# Symfony2, dynamically refresh form choices

Tags: ajax, forms, symfony

I am creating a simple Blog system with symfony2. Each blog **Post** is bound to a certain amount of **Tags**.

Tags can be selected with checkboxes when creating a new blog post. Now I want to be able to dynamically add new tag-checkboxes to the form.

The AJAX part is done and working, I can add new tag names to the Tag entity and append the new checkboxes to the form.

The problem is when I submit the form, symfony2 doesn't recognize the new added tags because they don't belong to the Tag entity yet (at the time the form was generated).

For example: after submitting the form, I dump:

```
$tags = $form->get('tags')->getData();
```

The controller ignores the tags that were added through ajax.

I know it has to be solved with events somehow, I already read this documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html  but can't figure out how to implement it for this specific case.

Here is my form builder for "PostType":

```
$builder
        ->add('title')
        ->add('content', 'textarea')
        ->add('tags', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'Bundle:Tag',
            'property' => 'name',
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
        ))
        ->add('save', 'submit')
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this: [Form Collection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you persist the newly added Tags before submit the form, and the checkboxes has the right names and values.

Names should be like "post[tags][]" and values should be the database ids of the Tag entities.